# How to make an array of Strings to store words of a "dictionary" from a .txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, string, dictionary

I need to make a *dictionary* that takes words from a `.txt` file. These words (separated line by line) need to be stored in a `String` array. I have already gotten to the point of separating the words and adding them to a new `.txt` file, but I have no idea how to add them each to a `String` array. There are

Comment: What do you mean by "dictionary"? a hash of key-value pairs? if so, that can ve achieved with a `HashMap`

Comment: By dictionary, I mean like that is our actual assignment. We are suppose to read through the lines of a .txt file (its a book in a .txt file) and scan each word to check if it is lower case, etc. Then we have to add all these words to an Array of Strings and after we scan all 3 of these different .txt files, it will add every String from the array onto a new .txt file called Dictionary.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the lines in the file.  Create an *array* of that size.

Then for each line in the file, *read* it and *insert* it into the *array* at the `index[lineReadFrom]`.

Comment: If you would be willing to show me over skype what you mean by this, that would be helpful. Because I feel like I did that and I am still getting errors.

Comment: I posted the code. Maybe you could take a look and see if I am on the right track. Thank you tom!

Comment: You are creating the array everytime you go through the while loop.  Only create the array once.  Work out how big it should be /before/ you start adding things to it.

Comment: Okay. I placed it outside of the loop and now I am still getting the same error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Dictionary.searchText(Dictionary.java:47) Line 47 is the "dict[i] = word" in my code. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Start again.  Count the lines in the file.  Create an array of that size.  then loop though the file adding words to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not allowed to use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` objects, I would suggest to save every found word "on the fly" while you are reading the input file. These is a series of steps you could follow to get this done:

**1. Read the file, line by line:** Use the common `new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file"))` approach and read line by line (as I assume you are already doing, looking at your code).

**2. Check every line for words:** Break every possilbe word by spaces with a `String.split()` and remove punctuation characters.

**3. Save every word:** Loop through the String array returned by the `String.split()` and for every element that you considered a word, update your statistics and write it to your dictionary file with the common `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("")).write(...);`

**4. Close your resources:** Close the reader an writer after you finished looping through them, preferably in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File dictionaryFile = new File("dict.txt");

    // Count the number of lines in the file
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(dictionaryFile));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);

    // Instantiate a String[] with the size = number of lines
    String[] dict = new String[lnr.getLineNumber() + 1];
    lnr.close();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dictionaryFile);
    int wordNumber = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        if (word.length() >= 2 && !(Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0)))) {
            dict[wordNumber] = word;
            wordNumber++;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

It took about `350 ms` to finish executing on a 118,620 line file, so it should work for your purposes. Note that I instantiated the array in the beginning instead of creating a new `String[]` on each line (and replacing the old one like you did in your code).

I used `wordNumber` to keep track of the current array index so that each word would be added to the array at the right location.

I also used `.nextLine()` instead of `.next()` since you said that the dictionary was separated by line instead of by spaces (which is what `.next()` uses).